# NSUInteger not appearing properly on TestFlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuinteger

I've been testing my app on the simulator and device. There are labels that show NSIntegers and I've formatted them as:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)_qty]
```

This works. However, when I build my app for TestFlight, these labels come out as numbers like `580023223`, for example.

I initialised _qty this way:

```
NSUInteger _qty;

_qty = 0;
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: `qty` is initialized correctly in test scenario?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly on the device and simulator. Only when I create the IPA and test it on the device or TestFlight, it doesn't appear properly anymore?

Comment: The posted code is correct. Your problem is elsewhere. Check initialization of `_qty`.

Comment: you should share more source code

Comment: how does   NSUInteger _qty; initialize an integer? :)

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: Don't use underscore to prefix variables. Especially not on iOS just looks messy, variable names begin with a lowercase letter. Please show all your code from creating the `qty` variable to displaying it in the label.

Comment: @Fogmeister I assume the OP declared `_qty` as an ivar where it's common to use the underscore prefix. Anyway — this question cannot be answered without more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialise a variable with a value, it would have a random value from memory. You should try that:

```
NSUInteger _qty = 0;
```

Comment: Can you show the code between the initialisation and the stringWithFormat line?